# ruby 3.0.4, redmine 5.0.0, rails 6.1.4, test install start with webrick fails, "wrong number of arguments"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments, redmine, webrick

New ubuntu-20 system with the following:

```
  ruby 3.0.4
  rails 6.1.4
  redmine 5.0.0
```

After install, trying to start webrick test server:

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e redmine_test
```

fails with:

```
/home/test_user/.gem/ruby/3.0.4/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:525:in `handle_argument_error':
  ERROR: "rails server" was called with arguments ["webrick"] (Thor::InvocationError)
Usage: "rails server -u [thin/puma/webrick] [options]"
        from .../thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:34:in `rescue in run'
        from .../thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:20:in `run'
        from .../thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from .../thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from .../railties-6.1.4.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from .../railties-6.1.4.7/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from .../railties-6.1.4.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
.../railties-6.1.4.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform':
  wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
        from .../thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from .../thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from .../thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from .../railties-6.1.4.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from .../railties-6.1.4.7/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from .../railties-6.1.4.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

It's not clear to me which arguments / syntax it's complaining about; I've tried different combinations and all complain about wrong number of arguments:

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e redmine_test        (given 1, expected 0)
bundle exec rails server webrick -e=redmine_test        (given 1, expected 0)
RAILS_ENV=redmine_test bundle exec rails server webrick (given 1, expected 0)
bundle exec rails server webrick redmine_test           (given 2, expected 0)
bundle exec rails server webrick                        (given 1, expected 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command-line format seems to have changed for Rails 6:

```
> rails server --help
Usage:
  rails server -u [thin/puma/webrick] [options]
               ^^
```

You may also need to add webrick to your Gemfile:

```
bundle add webrick
```

Comment: Thanks.  But now it complains about "Could not load server "webrick". Maybe add to Gemfile?  But it is in Gemfile.lock, although not in Gemfile.

Comment: @GaryAitken You could try `bundle add webrick; bundle install` to make sure. On my system it works, but i have webrick among my system gems.

Comment: Can't remember what I did, I think "bundle add webrick".  Thanks.  I'm almost there, but can't get passenger to start under apache; a gem path problem that doesn't make sense to me -- [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72339642/apache-passenger-rails-ruby-redmine-rails-startup-gem-path-problem)

Comment: The solution (using the -u) saved my time. Thanks a lot! So finally the command needed to run is `bundle exec rails server -u webrick -e redmine_test`

Answer (score 0):

Casper showed that solution and I am rearranging the solution point by point here.

1. Add `webrick` if it's not already installed. `bundle add webrick`
2. Run `bundle exec rails server -u webrick -e redmine_test`
   Look at the last keyword `redmine_test`. It's the enviroment that you are using for this case. So, write `production` if you are trying to run it in production.